# Place all axis labels at left and bottom in R lattice xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to alter the default xyplot setting where the axis labels alternate by panel.

```
xyplot(yield~N | P+K, data=npk)
```

[image]

I realize that it is intentional to avoid overlaps of axis extremes on neighboring panels, but for categorical x-axis labels as shown above, it is not necessary and looks odd for publication.

Is there a way to put all axis labels on the same side as shown below (which I edited in a graphics program)?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While checking to make sure I didn't duplicate a question, I tried some new search terms and found the solution buried in the lengthy xyplot help file.

There is a parameter called “scales” that itself has a bunch of parameters that you can specify, and it has to be in a list. The default for `alternating` is `TRUE` and switching it to `FALSE` will do the trick:

```
xyplot(yield~N | P+K, data=npk, scales=list(alternating=FALSE))
```

[image]

You can also enter a numeric value for this parameter to determine what side the labels should go on:

```
xyplot(yield~N | P+K, data=npk, scales=list(alternating=1))
xyplot(yield~N | P+K, data=npk, scales=list(alternating=2))
```

You can pass it multiple parameters to have each panel behave differently:

```
xyplot(yield~N | P+K, data=npk, scales=list(alternating=c(1,0)))
```

Default here is `c(1,2)`